# Django - Cannot filter by foreign key first_name

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-views

So currently im making so, you can search users that are attending an even, by some filters that are `first_name, last_name, username`

The error is currently

> too many values to unpack (expected 2)
>
> Errorline in view:

```
makefilter = "user__"+searchfilter+"__contains="+searchinput

usersearch = TeamMembership.objects.filter(makefilter)
```

How can I successfully search by the filters?

#### My views.py:

```
def volunteer(request):
    ## init context
    context = {}
    ## Get filters if somes
    searchfilter = request.GET.get('filter', None)
    searchinput = request.GET.get('searchinput', None)
    ## Checks if filter is not none or null or empty
    if searchfilter != "" and searchfilter != None and searchinput != "" and searchinput != None:
        ## Great now check what filter is used
        ## Now strip the filters for whitespaces
        searchfilter.strip()
        searchinput.strip()
        ## This filter is for teams
        if searchfilter == "teamname":
            teamsearch = Team.objects.all().filter(name__contains=searchinput)
            context['teams'] = True
            context['search'] = teamsearch
        ## This filter is for users
        elif searchfilter == "first_name" or searchfilter == "last_name" or searchfilter == "username" or searchfilter == "phone":
            makefilter = "user__"+searchfilter+"__contains="+searchinput
            usersearch = TeamMembership.objects.filter(makefilter)
            context['users'] = True
            context['search'] = usersearch
    return render(request, 'volunteer/hqvolunteer.html', context)
```

#### My model im trying to search user model are standard Django auth:

```
class TeamMembership(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team)
    ingroup = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    leader = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    groupleader = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Try to understand the meaning of the error.  "too many values to unpack" arises when you try to iterate over a python dictionary without using `iteritems` or `items`. Re-read the code block (view file) again to inspect any such use/access of dictionary object

Comment: This error would only occur if it is expected 2  elements but return more or less than 2 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you only construct a *string*, and perhaps, that is shaped like Python code, but this is not how you pass arbitrary parameter *names* to a function.

What you here can use is *keyword parameters*, and construct a dictionary that maps a *key* (the name of the parameter) to a *value* (the value that should correspond with that parameter), like:

```
some_dict = { "user__"+searchfilter+"__contains": searchinput}

usersearch = TeamMembership.objects.filter(**some_dict)
```

In case the `search_filter` is for example `'email'`, and `searchinput` being `'bar'`, then this will result in `some_dict` being `{ 'user__email__contains': 'bar' }`, and calling:

```
TeamMembership.objects.filter(**{ 'user__email__contains': 'bar' })
```

is equivalent to:

```
TeamMembership.objects.filter(user__email__contains='bar')
```

If you want to filter over multiple items, you can construct a dictionary with multiple keys. Note however that the keys - like parameter names - can not clash (calling a function with twice or more the same *named* parameter).

Furthermore beware, a `User` model contains (*hashed*) passwords, and other sensitive data, you might want to avoid filtering on some fields, since one can use this mechanism to hack data out of the system.

Comment: Thank you very much I'd never filtered with foreign keys before so this one was new for me and of course not all field can be used